# How to merge cells with same value in CSV file in Netsuite script?

Tags: csv, netsuite

I created a Suitelet script to export a CSV file with all employee details. In CSV file, I want to merge the cells for same employee name.
Can you please suggest how to do this in suitescript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you created a suitelet that generates the CSV file, you should have access to where the cell data is generated (and in essence be able to do the merging there).

Comment: I want to merge cells in suitelet itself. As it is CSV, I didn't specify any row/columns for it, then how should I merge cells with same data?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help you with this. Please post some example code that shows how you are generating the csv file. Without that, it's difficult to suggest anything.